# Finding World War 2 Army or Navy service record for resident of Sussex, England?

Tags: military-records, united-kingdom, world-war-2

Peter Evelyn Graham was born in 1923 in London and died in 1972 in Sussex. He was in the services but not sure which one:

- Army records, his name hasn't come up.
- Navy records have a leading seaman Navy auxillary.

All the sites I have tried that say they have records of that name all want me to take out a membership. I do not wish to do that, I only want that one piece of information.

I have assumed rightly or wrongly the time period would have been 1943-1945. I have tried the Sussex Army regiment but drew a blank.

I live in Australia so can only search online.

Some years ago I was able to get a grandfather's military record online and they only charged me 2 pounds. The trouble is that I cannot remember the site.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [tour] which leads into our [help/on-topic] where you will see we have to be very careful when asking about anyone born less than 100 years ago.  That is why your ancestor's name has been removed from your question.  Don't worry, we want to and should be able to help, we just need to take some care about how we do it.

Comment: I have restored your ancestor's name because I have found his death registered in Dec 1972 at Hove, Sussex online at Ancestry.com. England & Wales, Death Index, 1916-2007 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations Inc, 2007.  However, I could not find a military record for Peter Evelyn Graham there, or on FindMyPast. There are a few Peter Grahams but none jumped out as being this one in the quick search that I did.

Comment: The leading seaman Navy Auxiliary was born many years before 1923 and died in service, according to Forces-war-records.co.uk

Comment: Have you tried his 1939 Register record? He's living in the Mecklenburgh Household, Hove M.B., Sussex, England. Could hold some info about him. Also, I live just outside Hove and most of my Ancestors are from within 10m of Brighton, would be interesting to see what street he lived on. (Go to Findmypast and search the 1939 register for Peter E Graham)

Comment: Thank you Tony, yes I do have the 1939 record and most of the family history.
As you can see I am new to this site so not aware of the protocol. I will try the link you suggested. My main problem is not knowing which Service he was in.

Answer (score 3):

As he died more than 25 years ago, you (or anyone) can apply for a copy of his full service record. These are still held by the Ministry of Defence.

You will need to supply a copy of his death certificate, and applications cost £30.

Details on how to apply are here:

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/requests-for-personal-data-and-service-records#service-records-of-deceased-service-personnel