# Finding my father's Royal Navy record for WWII?

Tags: military-records, united-kingdom, world-war-2, navy

I have tried many times to find a record of my father who was in the navy during WWII without success. He told me that he served in minesweepers and then on motor gun boats and ended up serving in Ceylon. I know that we have an unusual surname Duguid and that it may have been misspelt but none of the various sites list him or names spelt like Duguid. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  If your father was born less than 100 years ago please be aware of the Privacy Policy in our [help/on-topic].  We will do our best to help but there are some constraints there that you may be able to help us work with by providing information like your father's birth year, and if he is deceased perhaps a link to a death notice or obituary.

Comment: @TomH This answer https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2265/1006 does have a useful suggestion for this case, but it doesn't offer any practical advice on how to order the records from the MOD.  I think we could make room for a Q on how to find WW2 records for service members who survived the war, since the advice on checking the various war memorials won't necessarily help.

Comment: This answer https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/10446/104 covers ordering the records from the MOD @JanMurphy